# What to return when dequeue is called on an empty templated C++ Queue class

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures

I have a templated Queue class in C++, with a dequeue function

```
template <typename el>
class Queue {
public: 
  ...
  el dequeue();
  ...
private: 

...
};
```

The dequeue function is defined as

```
template <typename el>
el Queue<el>::dequeue() {
  if(isEmpty()) {
    std::cout<<"The queue appears to be empty"<<std::endl;
    // What should I return here ? 
  } else {
   ...
  }
}
```

If I had a non templated class or say a simple Queue that only dealt with integers I could've returned a value like -1 or something, and stopped the execution of the dequeue function. What should I do in this case since el could be a structure, object or a primitive data type.

Comment: have you considered to use `std::quque` ?

Comment: @DavidHaim I am actually building this queue data structure myself as an exercise.

Comment: `throw` an exception.

Comment: There's really nothing you *can* return there. Many implementation would just throw an exception in that case, other just return a default constructed element and hope for the best.

Comment: The benefit of an exception over a default-constructed argument is that you don't rely on a default constructor. This is a good thing. Another option is simply to _not_ return anything. Undefined Behavior, sure, but that is also how the STL containers work. Most attempts to work with non-existing elements fail in that way, `std::map::operator[ ]` being the main exception.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to just throw an exception. This signals that an error has occurred and client code can react accordingly.

Another possibility would be to `return el{};` to default-construct an `el`. Of course, this requires `el` to be default-constructible, which may or may not be a reasonable constraint for you. However, this places the onus on client code to do size validation so that it can tell the difference between a `dequeue` on an empty `Queue` and a valid return equal to the default constructed `el`.

Comment: It could tell the difference by querying the size of the queue. But, if I know the size is 0, I won't dequeue in the first place. That's why throwing an exception makes sense. Alternatively, you could pass a reference as parameter, get it copied and return an int for success/failure.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on what TartanLlama have said:
the starndard library returns an *iterator* to the result. you can think about iterator as a wrapped pointer which used to traverse containers. 
when you don't have something good to return - you return a pointer to the (no-existing) one after the last element.

in your example, if `Queue` is done for exercise, you can return `el*` isntead of `el` as the return type of `dequeue`  and return `nullptr` if you don't have something good to return.

you can also think about implementing `Optional` class.
the idea behind `Optional` is to have a wrapper class that may or may not contain a result. you implement `bool` operator to check if the object actually contain a valid value. a skeleton to such a class may look like:

```
template <class T>
class Optional{

T* m_optional;

public:

Optional(T* t);
Optional(T& t);

T* operator -> ();
operator bool() const;

};
```

then your return `Optional<el>` from `Queue`

of course, on real code , just use `std::queue`